# Finding the integral of the natural log to a high power

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm looking to solve the following integral:

$$ \int_{2}^{9}{(\ln{x})^{49}}dx $$

I'm aware of the following reduction formula for the natural log:

$$ \int{(\ln x)^ndx} = x(\ln x)^n - n\int{(\ln x)^{n-1}dx} $$

But it seems like solving this would take a very long time. I feel like there must be some kind of trick to solve this without having to use the reduction formula, but I can't seem to find one.

Comment: If you meant to write $(\ln x)^{49}$ I would edit accordingly.  As it stands, I'd have read what you wrote as $\ln (x^{49})=49\ln x$.

Comment: But is that really what you meant?  With $(\ln x)^{49}$, the answer is $>2\times 10^{16}$, see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+%28ln%28x%29%29%5E49+from+2+to+9)

Comment: A very long time? Not really. A minute or two of repeated use of the formula before you spot the pattern and can jump straight to the end, maybe. Hoping for a better way is always nice, but some times you really do need just a little perseverance.

Comment: @Arthur It turns out the other posters are right, the question is actually $ \ln{x^{49}} = 49\ln{x}$ .I think I found the pattern for my original question though, I think I can do $49!x(\frac{(lnx)^{49}}{49!}-\frac{(lnx)^{48}}{48!}-\frac{(lnx)^{47}}{47!}...)$. Would this have been the way to go?

Comment: @mars_plastic seems like the best way unless you're willing to express in terms of say some incomplete gamma functions

Comment: @mars_plastic Apart from the fact that I think the signs should alternate, yeah, that looks about right.

Comment: $$
\int_{}^{} {\log ^m xdx}  = x\sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {( - 1)^k k!\binom{m}{k}\log ^{m - k} x} 
$$ for $m=1,2,3,\ldots$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me consider the generalized case,
$$\int_{a}^{b}(\ln x)^{c}dx$$
$$x=e^{u}\implies dx=e^{u}du$$
$$\int_{\ln a}^{\ln b}u^{c}e^{u}du$$
Using the series expansion of e,
$$e=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{1}{k!}$$
$$\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{1}{k!}\int_{\ln a}^{\ln b}u^{c+k}du$$
$$\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{1}{(k!)(k+c+1)}((\ln a)^{k+c+1}-(\ln b)^{k+c+1})$$

Comment: Use \ln to produce $\ln$. Also you use the power series of $e^u$ and not the series definition of $e$. Look at my comment above for a simple finite expansion.